# Nginx Upload Progress Module

Tags: php, upload, nginx

**I have a pretty wide-spreaded question .... I don't understand how Upload Progress Module works  , and it kind of doesn't work for me too , so ....**

1) I have installed nginx with all the upload modules (nginx, nginx-extras) , and php-fpm

2)This is part of my nginx config for the project:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/cha0s/learnphp$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;

  track_uploads proxied 1m;
}

location ~ ^/files/(.*)$ {
        alias /home/cha0s/$1;
        internal;
}

location ^~ /progress {
        # report uploads tracked in the 'proxied' zone
        report_uploads proxied;
}
```

3)I followed the tutorial at the bottom of this page: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule :

So i have a form  and upload progress bar:

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.html" method="post">
  <input name="file" type="file"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
<div id="uploading">
  <div id="progress" class="bar">
    <div id="progressbar"> </div>
    <div id="percents"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS code that triggers the jquery script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('form').uploadProgress({
        /* scripts locations for safari */
        jqueryPath: "/static/js/jquery.js",
        uploadProgressPath: "/static/js/jquery.uploadProgress.js",
        /* function called each time bar is updated */
        uploading: function(upload) {$('#percents').html(upload.percents+'%');},
        /* selector or element that will be updated */
        progressBar: "#progressbar",
        /* progress reports url */
        progressUrl: "/progress",
        /* how often will bar be updated */
        interval: 2000
      }
    });
  </script>
```

And that script : 
https://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress/blob/master/jquery.uploadProgress.js

Questions and Problems:

1)First problem is that i always get returned  ({ "state" : "starting" }); ...

2)Second question is : the reason i began trying to make this thing work , is because i wanted to write a php script , which would slice file into chunks and send them to the server , so i could upload huge files , and have a progress bar to monitor it. But i couldn't even find the smallest example or tutorial how to get it done with php and upload_progress_module or w/e.

And no , i don't want flash based uploaders.

**So i guess  , you already understood that i am a confused. So if you could explain how i can get this done, and help solve the problem with already existing configuration would be great**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action="index.html"` doesn't look like the request that goes to `location ~ \.php$`.

Comment: emm tha's a typo ... sorry ... i have it set in my file to test.php. Just copy pasted that part from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still experiencing issues with this but see below for some solutions...

1. No upload_pass value specified
2. No upload_store specified
3. Once specified an upload_store hashed directory needs to be created with correct permissions
4. It would make more sense to add the action "/upload" to the form and send the form to this location on your upload domain (if different from the forms domain)
5. I think that based on the 'starting' value of the json returned I would look at the directory issue in points 2 and 3 first
6. The form needs to be passed to you upload location with a GET parameter of 'X-Progress-ID=[a custom upload id number]' so that it can track the status